# Issue with Gunicorn in Docker - "Worker (pid:649) was sent SIGTERM!" error

Tags: python, docker, flask, gunicorn

I've set up a Flask API running with Gunicorn inside a Docker container (with Docker Desktop on Windows 11). Everything seems to be working fine, but I'm encountering a recurring issue. Occasionally, I see the following error message in Gunicorn logs:

```
[1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:649) was sent SIGTERM!
```

[image: docker logs]

I've provided my Dockerfile and the gunicorn.conf.py file for reference:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.10

# Creating Application Source Code Directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

# Setting Home Directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Installing python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN python -m playwright install
RUN python -m playwright install-deps

# Copying src code to Container
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Exposing Ports
EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:5000", "-c", "gunicorn.conf.py", "run:app"]
```

**gunicorn.conf.py:**

```py
workers = 3  # 2 * (CPU cores) + 1
loglevel = "info"
accesslog = "-"
capture_output = True
enable_stdio_inheritance = True
```

Why is the SIGTERM error occurring? Are there any improvements I can make to the configuration?

Comment: **DO NOT** use screenshots for plain text -- such as the three lines from the log file you included. They are hard to read and we can't copy/paste the text in the image. I googled "gunicorn sigterm" and found several documents that seem relevant. Such as https://lucasklassmann.com/devlog/2024-03-05-gunicorn-custom-worker-sigterm/. Also, I am quite confident you have not included all relevant information. Which is to say, I don't think this has anything to do with your Gunicorn or Docker config.

Answer (score 1):

If the workers are taking too long to boot, or running into timeouts, you can also adjust the [Gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) configuration file `gunicorn.conf.py` to increase the number of workers or adjust the timeout settings:

```py
import multiprocessing

workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1  # Adjust the number of workers
timeout = 30  # Adjust the timeout as necessary, default is 30 seconds
graceful_timeout = 30  # Wait 30 seconds after a restart signal for workers to finish
loglevel = "info"
accesslog = "-"
errorlog = "-"
capture_output = True
enable_stdio_inheritance = True
```

That would assume, as commented, that your custom Gunicorn worker is able to handle a SIGTERM, as illustrated in "**[Handling SIGTERM in Gunicorn](https://lucasklassmann.com/devlog/2024-03-05-gunicorn-custom-worker-sigterm/)**" from [Lucas Klassmann](https://www.linkedin.com/in/lucasklassmann/).

---

For testing, you could also try and start Gunicorn with a script to handle SIGTERM properly, to see if the same issue persists.

Create a `gunicorn_starter.sh` file (and make it executable: `chmod +x gunicorn_starter.sh`)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

function shutdown() {
    echo "Shutting down Gunicorn gracefully..."
    kill -SIGTERM "$pid"
    wait "$pid"
}

# Trap SIGTERM from Docker stop command and forward to the Gunicorn process
trap shutdown SIGTERM

# Start Gunicorn with configurations
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 -c gunicorn.conf.py run:app &

pid=$!
wait "$pid"
```

You need to add that file to your image in your Dockerfile:

```
# (the previous part of the Dockerfile remains unchanged)

# Exposing Ports
EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["/usr/src/app/gunicorn_starter.sh"]
```

---

> I've tested your solution and it makes no difference

Try and adjust the Gunicorn configuration (`gunicorn.conf.py`) to account for potential timeouts and resource constraints:

```py
import multiprocessing

workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1  # Dynamically set the number of workers
timeout = 120  # Allow workers up to 120 seconds to respond to their master process
graceful_timeout = 120  # Give workers up to 120 seconds to finish their work before restarting
loglevel = "info"
accesslog = "-"
errorlog = "-"
capture_output = True
enable_stdio_inheritance = True
```

Set `--log-level debug` in Gunicorn to log more detailed information about the worker state.
And use monitoring tools like `docker stats` to watch the container's resource usage.